# Getting "mismatched input 'a' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'" error

Tags: pine-script

I am using this code in Pine Script but getting the "mismatched input 'a' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'" error.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCBGk.jpg]

How to Fix This Error?

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Instead, copy&paste your code here and use the code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write your if statements in one line. You need to start the next line with a tab or 4 spaces.

```
if (buy)
    strategy.entry()
```